# IAPs work fine with App Tester, but hang in Live App Testing

Tags: in-app-purchase

I just updated to to the Amazon AppStore SDK 3.0.4 from the old billing library. Everything is working fine with App Tester, but the problem is that when I try to make an IAP in live app testing, the app just hangs. It looks like the issue is that the SDK is not able to create its UI. Here is the relevant line from logcat:

ForegroundTaskPipeline: No UI visible to execute task: com.amazon.device.iap.internal.a.e.a$1@c387587, placing into pending queue until task is visible

Any ideas?

Might Get Help From This but in React Native
Purchase dialog hangs in Amazon Fire devices on Live App Testing